# multiprocessing.Queue and Queue.Queue are different?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

If I use `Queue.Queue`, then my `read()` function doesn't work, why? But if I use `multiprocessing.Queue`, it works well:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Queue 
import os, time
# from Queue import Queue 

def write(q): 
    for v in ['A', 'B', 'C']: 
        print 'Put %s to queue ' % v 
        q.put_nowait(v) 
        time.sleep(0.2) 

def read(q): 
    while 1: 
        if not q.empty(): 
            v = q.get(True) 
            print "Get %s from queue" % v 
            time.sleep(0.2) 
        else: 
            break 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    q = Queue() 
    pw = Process(target=write, args=(q, )) 
    pr = Process(target=read, args=(q, )) 
    pw.start() 
    pw.join() 

    pr.start() 
    pr.join() 

    print "all done..."
```

Comment: Think about it this way: if they _weren't_ different, why would `multiprocessing.Queue` even exist? The whole point of it is to give you a `queue.Queue`-like object that also works between separate processes.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`Queue.Queue` is just an in-memory queue that knows how to deal with multiple threads using it at the same time. It only works if both the producer and the consumer are in the same process.

Once you have them in separate system processes, which is what the `multiprocessing` library is about, things are a little more complicated, because the processes no longer share the same memory. You need some kind of inter-process communication method to allow the two processes to talk to each other. It can be a shared memory, a pipe or a socket, or possibly something else. This is what `multiprocessing.Queue` does. It uses pipes to provide a way for two processes to communicate. It just happens to implement the same API as `Queue.Queue`, because most Python programmers are already familiar with it.

Also note that the way you are using the queue, you have a race condition in your program. Think about what happens if the `write` process writes to the queue right after you call `q.empty()` in the `read` process. Normally you would add some special item to the queue (e.g. `None`) which would mean that the consumer can stop.

Comment: I've found q.empty() for Multiprocessing.Queue to be *extremely* unreliable. It's wrong more often than it's right, frankly. Not even a race condition issue: you can have Process A stick something in the queue when Process B is sleeping, and later invoke empty() from Process B - it reports empty, no matter how long the item has been waiting there. A much better option is checking whether qsize() > 0 - which is not perfect, but *much* more consistently correct.

Comment: One FYI regarding multiprocessing.Queue (as a behavioral difference over queue.Queue): Data inserted into the queue *must* be read out. If a process writes to a queue and later terminates, it will not actually terminate until another process takes the item of the queue.